# Is it possible to internalize/IL-merge a single C# class?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, .net-assembly, ilmerge

I have an app with a reference to a rather large library DLL (let's call it `lib.dll`), but it only uses a single class from it (let's call this `Helper`).

`lib.dll` has additional transitive references which are all copied to the `bin` folder of my project upon compilation.

I would seriously like to avoid that overhead and find a way to "copy" or "cross-compile" or "merge" the code that makes up `Helper` into my main project.

Are there any possibilities for doing so? I would like to avoid IL-merging `lib.dll` in its entirity.

Comment: What if `HelperClass` has some depoendencies to other classes or assemblies also? That would make this question into something quite complex. In worst scenario you´re ending on copying the entire assembly and all its dependencies into your program anyway.

Comment: @HimBromBeere you are right, but in my case it is really a simple class.

Comment: @close-voters: "too broad" I could argue with. "unclear" => please specify?

Comment: Overhead?  What overhead?  .NET assemblies strongly support the "you don't pay for what you don't use" paradigm provided by a demand-paged virtual memory operating system.  A desire for cleanliness is a good programmer trait, but that applies to source code, not bytes.

Comment: @HansPassant Perhaps overhead was a poor word choice, but the overhead I was talking about lies in deployment. Of course we have automated systems etc so there's no *real* issue here, but I'm just curious if I could eliminate the 10 extra dll/pdb files I *don't* need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some situations you can just embed the third party dlls as embedded resources and resolve the references yourself, as Jeffrey Richter described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition/).

In a nutshell, in your entry point:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) => {
    string name = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name;

    // Either hardcode the appropriate namespace or retrieve it at runtime in a way that makes sense for your project.
    string resourceName = string.Concat("My.Namespace.Resources.", name, ".dll");

    using(var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)) {
        var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        return Assembly.Load(buffer);
    }
};
```

Comment: Interesting. How does it perform compared to letting the CLR (JIT?) just do its thing w.r.t. assembly loading?

Comment: I honesty have only used this technique once: I had a splash screen that also served as a zip file extractor and I was tired of shipping Ionic.Zip.dll with it. I could not detect any major degradation in performance, but I was only resolving one dll with no other referenced dlls.

Comment: Also, I updated the code to fix a copy/paste issue where I omitted a necessary variable declaration.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using .NET Core the new [.NET Linker](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3220995/open-source-tools/microsoft-linker-tool-shrinks-net-applications.html) would be an option. Otherwise, license permitting, and if the class you use does not have too many dependencies and the dll is not obfuscated, you could just copy the code to your application by decompiling the dll with [IL Spy](http://ilspy.net/)

Comment: That Linker looks amazingly interesting! I agree just copying over the code is an option, but in my case, I have access to the actual source and would like to specifically maintain it where it is because the `lib.dll` is spread around elsewhere.

Comment: I was just about the suggest the Mono Linker, that the .NET LInker is actually  based on. Maybe that can be used with full .NET assemblies as well.
https://github.com/mono/linker

Comment: If you have access to the code, and it's in the same repo, another version would be to link the file in your project

Comment: @AkosNagy I saw the mono linker as well not sure if it is being maintained or if it was superseded by the .NET Linker

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir it's not in the same repo unfortunately, otherwise I would have definitely used file linking.